# synthetic belly

Tags: word-meaning

This is an excerpt from [a *The Atlantic* article](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2022/02/gun-safety-hollywood-alec-baldwin/622836/).

> But sometimes, no amount of coaching helps. There’s an actor—and no,
> Davis won’t name this one—who Davis says has shot him accidentally
> (and absent-mindedly) four different times on the set of four
> different films. When Davis works with a performer, he always tries to
> ensure that the star is listening, to go over safety protocols, and to
> repeat warnings about the dangers of prop guns, because even blanks
> can harm when fired in close proximity. But still, with this actor?
> Bang. Eventually, Davis started wearing a thick **synthetic belly** around
> his waist whenever he knew they’d be working together.

Is a **synthetic belly** a bulletproof vest or literally a fake belly made of syntetic material?

Comment: I've never heard this term, but to me it seems most likely that it's theater/movie prop designed to make someone seem overweight or pregnant. A bulletproof vest is called a vest for a reason, and protecting the heart is an important, if not essential feature.

Comment: I looked up "synthetic belly" and found artificial bellies to look pregnant, and something called a "[synthetic belly protector](https://twinsfight.com/twins-special-synthetic-belly-protector-w-velcro-boxing-muay-thai-mma-martial-arts-black-red-blue/)", which seems somewhat closer to the context. I'm guessing this question is unanswerable

Comment: @RDBury I've converted your answer to a comment. Please leave guesses in the comments, and only post things you're sure of as answers.

Comment: @I'll keep that in mind. I'm normally on the SE for German Language where the policy is to put anything resembling an answer in an answer; comments are mostly reserved for clarifying the question. In fact posting the above remark in a comment there would likely provoke an angry "Please don't answer in the comments!" response. I didn't realize other SE's would have different policies.